# Bridge table question

Tags: database-design

Should be a simple questions, I just want to make sure.

If I had 2 tables I want to bridge, for example food (food_id, foodname, ...) and a plate (plate_id, platetype, ..). When the tables are bridged, would they need to be foreign keys to each other or it wont be necessary as there is a food_plate table with food_id and plate_id ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will indeed want a third table (*food_plate*) with two foreign keys, *food_id* to the *food* table and *plate_id* to the *plate* table. The *food* and *plate* tables should **not** reference each other.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Andriy M. I think this and Kenneth's answers helped me. :)

Comment: @Raneej13: You should thank Milney, not me. I only brushed up the formatting a little, the answer itself is not mine.

Comment: @Miley, I did not realize it as your answer that was edited. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

There wouldn't be a foreign key between the two tables because there is no relationship between them.

You have

Food (Food_Id), Plate (Plate_Id), and Food_Plate(Food_Id, Plate_Id)

- Food -> Food_Plate
- Plate -> Food_Plate

Food doesn't have a direct relationship to plate at all.

To try a different set of tables that might illustrate this a bit better try Teacher and Student with a cross table of Class

Teacher(Teacher_Id), Student(Student_Id), and Class (Class_Id, Teacher_Id, Student_Id)

- Teacher -> Class
- Student -> Class

But the Teacher has no relationship to the Student except through the class.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Kenneth Fisher. So a many to many relationship such as teacher/class or food/plate will have a bridge table and I would not have to define foreign keys because of it ?

Comment: You would add foreign keys between the individual tables and the cross/bridge table but not between each other.  Food to Food_Plate, and Plate to Food_Plate but not Food to Plate.